# Redirecting www to non-www (apache, letsencrypt )

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache-2.4, rewrite, lets-encrypt

Ubuntu 14.04
Apache 2.4.18

I have set up a SSL certificate using letsencrypt. It works well but in order to work, I cannot have multiple vhost defined in one virtualhost configuration file. Each vhost has to sit in its own .conf file inside /etc/apache2/sites-available.

I need to make sure all requests to www.example.com are redirected to example.com. 
Since I need to solve it inside the unique virtualhost file, I'm trying to include a rewrite rule inside to perform the redirection but so far it fails silently: all https://www.example.com requests are not being redirected to https://example.com and a "insecure website" warning is displayed.

Here is the virtualhost configuration file for domain.com-le-ssl.conf.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

        DocumentRoot /home/user_account/www/example.com/public
        <Directory /home/user_account/www/example.com/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/home/user_account/www/example.com/public/$1

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: To whom it may concern: care to explain the downvote ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your SSL certificate is not valid for www.example.com, when someone accesses your site using www.example.com, they will get a certificate warning. This happens regardless of whether they are served a redirect or not. Otherwise, it would be possible to create a redirect to any site at all and it would look trustworthy.

What you need to do is to either get a certificate that covers both www.example.com and example.com, or to set up a separate virtualhost for www.example.com, with a valid certificate, and put the redirect in that virtualhost.

Answer (score 1):

- You cannot include a redirection http -> https rule inside a SSL-enabled virtualhost. You cannot by design. Just accept it. You need a plain-HTTP virtualhost for doing redirection from HTTP (and this is your main mistake).
- Actually you can have just any config file inside your configuration directory in Debian-based Linux. You can even delete the dogmatic and uncomfortable `sites-*` directories and start using `vhost.d` directory, like I do. Nobody can force you use something that is uncomfortable.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point: AFAICS I'm not setting up a redirection from http -> https, but from https://www.domain.com to https://domain.com.

Comment: Do you test it accordingly ? And, anyway, what will happen if someone will just open your site (it will be opened via http). This is my point.

Comment: The http to https redirection is already set up and working, via a conf file listening to port 80.